# How can I run a command only after some other commands have run successfully?

Tags: linux, bash

In bash, I know I should use `&&` if I want a command `B` to be run only after command `A` succeeds:

```
A && B
```

But what if I want `D` to be run only after `A`, `B`, `C` all succeed?
Is

```
 'A&B&C' && D
```

OK?

Besides, what should I do if I want to know exactly which command failed, among `A`, `B` and `C` (as they will run many times, it will take a while if I check one by one).

Is it possible that the error info will be output to a text file automatically as soon as any command failed?

In my case, `A`, `B`, `C` are `curl` while `B` is `rm`, and my script is like this:

```
for f in * 
do 
    curl -T server1.com
    curl -T server2.com
    ...
    rm $f
done
```

Comment: Do you want to run `B` and `C` if `A` fails?  `A && B && C && D` will quit as soon as any command fails.  But if you want to run `A`, `B`, and `C` unconditionally, and then run `D` only if they all succeeded, then see @Adam's answer.  (No, `A&B&C && D` won't do what you want; the single `&` causes the command to be run in the background.)

Comment: can you use parenthesis maybe?

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
A; A_EXIT=$?
B; B_EXIT=$?
C; C_EXIT=$?
if [ $A_EXIT -eq 0 -a $B_EXIT -eq 0 -a $C_EXIT ]
then
  D
fi
```

The variables `A_EXIT`, `B_EXIT` and `C_EXIT` tell you which, if any, of the `A`, `B`, `C` commands failed. You can output to a file in an extra `if` statement after each command, e.g.

```
A; A_EXIT=$?
if [ $A_EXIT -ne 0 ]
then
  echo "A failed" > text_file
fi
```

Comment: Thank you for your help,can you tell what does "$?" mean?I seem to often meet it in bash script,but it can't be searched in google

Comment: $? is shell's special variable which holds the status of the last foreground command. One good place to search for these things is bash manpage: http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash

Answer (score 1):

why not store your commands in an array, and then iterate over it, exiting when one fails?

```
#!/bin/bash

commands=(
    [0]="ls"
    [1]="ls .."
    [2]="ls foo"
    [3]="ls /"
)

for ((i = 0; i < 4; i++ )); do
    ${commands[i]}
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        echo "${commands[i]} failed with $?"
        exit
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the return from the previous command by doing i.e

command ; echo $?

1 = failed
0 = success

In a more structured format, example:

```
cat /var/log/secure
  if [ $? -ne "1" ] ; then
    echo "Error" ; exit 1
  fi
```

Answer (score 0):

conditionally do something if a command succeeded or failed (acording to [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22726/how-to-conditionally-do-something-if-a-command-succeeded-or-failed) StackExchange answer)

```
if command ; then
    echo "Command succeeded"
else
    echo "Command failed"
fi
```

You can develop this simple code to execute multiple if conditions and also lets you know which command failed.

This might not be the perfect answer for question but thought it might help someone.